# Java image as ByteBuffer for OpenGL texture mapping

Tags: java, eclipse, opengl, image-processing, bytebuffer

I'm using openGL and trying to get my head around texture mapping.

At the moment, I have the following to add an image that I will use:

```
GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1);
GL11.glPixelStorei(GL11.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

GL11.glTexParameteri(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
GL11.glTexParameteri (GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL11.GL_REPEAT);
GL11.glTexParameteri (GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);
GL11.glTexParameteri (GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_LINEAR);

GL11.glTexEnvf(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL11.GL_MODULATE);

GL11.glTexImage2D(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, 32, 32, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, "imageData");
```

Where I have the string `"imageData"` I need a ByteBuffer for my image. How do I get this? The image is in my src folder in Eclipse.

Comment: ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(...)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested but looks like it would work

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(getBytesFromFile(filename));
```

There's an implementation of getBytesFromFile at http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/File2ByteArray.html

EDIT: Okay that example is really gone now, so here's an implementation of reading to a ByteBuffer

```
private static ByteBuffer readToBuffer(String filename) throws IOException
{
    File file = new File(filename);
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate((int) file.length());
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);

    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] buf = new byte[BYTES_PER_READ];

    while (bytesRead != -1)
    {
        bb.put(buf, 0, bytesRead);
        bytesRead = fis.read(buf);
    }

    fis.close();

    return bb;
}
```

Comment: Page not found on the link there.

Comment: The link works for me, anyway, it can be found easily by searching for "java read file as bytes"

Comment: this does only work if the image is a raw image already encoded in the correct format that opengl likes. So images like Bmp Png Jpg gif won't work

Comment: The post is meant to show how to turn files into a byte array per the OP's question.  I'm not making any claims that this will convert files into OpenGL texture friendly formats.

Comment: @jeff The question is "Java image as ByteBuffer". This doesn't show how to load an image into a bytebuffer. It shows how to load a file into a bytebuffer, which is useless for images without decoding.